# A debate class has 7 boys and 8 girls. If a team of 5 is to be chosen, what is the probability that the team will contain at least on girl?

Tags: statistics

I want to make sure that my thought process and math is correct. Thank you

$$\frac{{7\choose 4}{8\choose 1}}{{15\choose 5}}+\frac{{7\choose 3}{8\choose 2}}{{15\choose 5}}+\frac{{7\choose 2}{8\choose 3}}{{15\choose 5}}+\frac{{7\choose 1}{8\choose 4}}{{15\choose 5}}+\frac{{7\choose 0}{8\choose 5}}{{15\choose 5}}=\frac{(35)(8)}{3003}+\frac{(35)(28)}{3003}+\frac{(21)(56)}{3003}+\frac{(7)(70)}{3003}+\frac{(1)(56)}{3003}$$
$$=\frac{280}{3003}+\frac{980}{3003}+\frac{1176}{3003}+\frac{490}{3003}+\frac{56}{3003}=\frac{2982}{3003}=0.993=99.3\%$$

Comment: It may be easier to compute the probability that there will be no girls chosen and then subtract that from one.

Comment: Your answer is correct, as is your reasoning, but @JohnDouma is also correct: it’s easier to observe that there are $\binom75$ possible teams with no girl, so there are $\binom{15}5-\binom75=2982$ teams with at least one girl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather, you can take the complement:  If $A$ is the event that the team has at least one girl, then $A'$ is the event that the team has no girls.

As such, $$P(A)=1-P(A')=1-\frac{\binom75}{\binom{15}{5}}=1-\frac{21}{3003}=\frac{2982}{3003}\approx0.993.$$